# ionic3 plugin and platform errors

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native, ionic3

I am using ionic CLI version `3.0.0-beta.5`

When I am trying to install native plugins, I am getting these errors.
for example, installing `social-sharing` plugin

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing`

and the error is

> [ERROR] Unknown plugin: @ionic/cli-plugin-.

same error while adding platforms also..

```
C:\Users\varun\Desktop\apps\app>ionic platform add android
The platform command is no longer available. To find out more about the equivalent please run:

 ionic cordova:platform --help

C:\Users\varun\Desktop\apps\app>ionic cordova:platform --help
[ERROR] Unable to find command: cordova:platform. It is possible that you are trying to get help on a project based command and you are not in a project directory.
```

Has anyone faced this problem? I am not getting enough information on official blog.

Comment: Why you're using beta?

Comment: I wanted to check the differences between apps created by 2.2CLI and this beta one. so updated it :/

Answer (score 1):

To fix "The platform command is no longer available" issue on Ionic3 beta 7 I tried the following:

```
ionic cordova:platform add android
```

However, it only worked for newly started projects so need to update ionic-scripts in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git`

The repo name `cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing` is changed/missing

so, we can directly add plugin from plugin git repo.

```
shareWithOptions(option, successcallback, errorcallback);
```

Usage :

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareWithOptions( {
  message: 'share this',
  subject: 'the subject',
  files: ['', ''],
  url: 'https://www.gooogle.com',
  chooserTitle: 'Pick an app' 
  }, 
function(success){
  console.log(success);
  }, 
function(err){
 console.log(err);});
```